# How do I add a row manually in the Jquery array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Jquery code:

```
 var $affectedTRs = $('#location-usergroup-table tr[data-department-id="' + departmentID + '"')
```

So this contains all trs and I can run functions like find etc.

Now I want to push an item in this `$affectedTRs`

But this is not working:

```
$affectedTR.concat($('#location-usergroup-table tr[data-domain-id="' + domainID + '"'));
```

How do I push something manually in this selected object so I can have all Jquery functions like find etc available on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's add() method: https://api.jquery.com/add/

```
$newSelection = $affectedTR.add($('#location-usergroup-table tr[data-domain-id="' + domainID + '"'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want this:

```
$("#location-usergroup-table").append("<tr data-domain-id=\"" + domainID + "\""></tr>");
```

To add a new element to existing container, use `.append()`. [More details here](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Answer (score 0):

Your `$affectedTR` has all the rows i.e DOM elements. If you wish to create new row in the table, try [jquery append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)